# Склонение слова "сам" в значении наречия

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

*У меня всегда была мотивация развиваться и добиваться всего сам/самому/самим.*

Comment: О слове "сам" написано много работ, но мнения у различных авторов различны. Вы можете посмотреть небольшой обзор [по этой ссылке](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000015/st010.shtml). Там разобран случай, подобный Вашему, но я не могу оформить его в качестве ответа, поскольку он не достаточно идентичен.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ дополнен.

**У меня всегда была мотивация развиваться и добиваться всего  самому.**

1) **Я сам** (И.п.)всего добиваюсь. Надо всего добиваться **мне самому** (Д.п.). Это загадка и **для меня самого** (Р.п.). Несколько слов **обо мне самом** (П.п.).

2) С точки зрения грамматики, ***сам***  не является наречием, это  **определительное местоимение**, которое склоняется по образцу **прилагательных.**

3) С точки зрения семантики, местоимение ***сам*** может иметь значение "самостоятельно, без чьей-либо помощи",  то есть обстоятельственное значение, характерное для наречия, отнесенного  к глаголу.

В этом случае местоименное прилагательное ***сам*** имеет двунаправленную связь:

***Я всего добиваюсь сам.*** Добиваюсь (как?) сам (= самостоятельно), связь **примыкание**. **Я сам**, связь **согласование** в падеже и числе с дополнительным обозначением рода субъекта.

**У меня есть желание добиваться всего (мне) самому.** Добиваться (как?) самому.  (Мне) самому ― согласование в числе и падеже, обозначение рода действующего субъекта.

4) В сочетаниях ***для меня самого, обо мне самом*** местоимение "сам" имеет значение "лично" и относится к  местоимениям ***для меня, обо мне***, согласуясь с ними грамматически в падеже, числе и дополнительно обозначая род действующего субъекта (двунаправленной  связи здесь нет).

**И вывод:**

**Это всего лишь наблюдения,** и вопросов больше, чем ответов. Слово ***сам*** далеко не простое, связи  нестандартные, информацию о нем в вузовских учебниках желательно дополнить новыми исследованиями.

Comment: А почему вы выбрали именно д.п.? "Надо всего добиваться мне самому" — здесь понятно: надо кому-чему. Слово "надо" управляет существительным в дательном падеже. Но "У меня всегда была мотивация развиваться и добиваться всего самому", а также "У меня есть желание добиваться всего (мне) самому" — где здесь управляющее слово, которое требует дательного падежа?

Comment: Управление такое: добиваться (кому?)  (мне) самому, при чем тут "надо"? Надо добиваться - составное глагольное сказуемое с модальной связкой "надо", желание  (какое) добиваться  - несогласованное определение, выраженное инфинитивом. И этот инфинитив в обоих случаях управляет Д.п. местоимения.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста. Нигде не видел, чтобы "добиваться" управляло д. п. "Это помогало ему добиваться успеха", "Мне надо добиваться успеха" — везде управляющим является не инфинитив, а глагол-сказуемое — "помогало" и "надо".

Comment: У меня (у нее, у них) всегда была мотивация (какая?) развиваться и добиваться всего самому (самой, самим). Добиваться  (как?) самому  (= САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО). Пожалуй, вы правы.  Местоимение «самому, самой, самим» имеет здесь ЧАСТИЧНЫЕ ПРИЗНАКИ  НАРЕЧИЯ:  управления Д.п. нет,  вместо управления используется связь  «примыкание», но сохраняется согласование в роде и числе с существительным.

Comment: Сочетание «добиваться самому»  образуется НА ОСНОВЕ СТАНДАРТНОЙ КОНСТРУКЦИИ с Д.п.: мне (ей) надо всего добиваться самому (самой);  надо мне, надо самому. Но это сочетание  (КАК ЕДИНОЕ ЦЕЛОЕ) может использоваться в других предложениях (без управления Д.п.) : У меня есть желание  (какое?) добиваться всего самому. В этом случае всё сочетание выполняет роль несогласованного определения. К сожалению, в  словаре я не вижу подобных примеров.http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=сам